# Webpack 4 + fullySpecified option

Tags: webpack, es6-modules, webpack-4

I have a project that currently uses webpack 4 - the team doesn't want to upgrade right now.

webpack 5 has this option https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#resolvefullyspecified

```
fullySpecified: false
```

Does anyone know if the same can be achieved in Webpack 4 somehow?